# Including dynamic libraries using automake and autoconf

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, autoconf, automake

I am trying to include some dynamic libraries (.so files) for a simple 3D game I am making on linux using C++. These dynamic libraries are for using the Bullet physics engine.

I have very limited knowledge of how use automake and autoconf so any help would be much appreciated.

How might I modify any of the following files to include these dynamic libraries?

Here is my makefile.am:

```
noinst_HEADERS= BaseApplication.h Physics.h GameApplication.h

bin_PROGRAMS= OgreApp
OgreApp_CPPFLAGS= -I$(top_srcdir)
OgreApp_SOURCES= BaseApplication.cpp Physics.cpp GameApplication.cpp
OgreApp_CXXFLAGS= $(OGRE_CFLAGS) $(OIS_CFLAGS)
OgreApp_LDADD= $(OGRE_LIBS) $(OIS_LIBS)

EXTRA_DIST = buildit makeit
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
```

Here is my configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT(configure.ac)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(SampleApp, 0.1)
AM_CONFIG_HEADER(config.h)

AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS
AC_PROG_CXX
AM_PROG_LIBTOOL

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(OGRE, [OGRE >= 1.2])
AC_SUBST(OGRE_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(OGRE_LIBS)

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(OIS, [OIS >= 1.0])
AC_SUBST(OIS_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(OIS_LIBS)

AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

I also have a buildit file that sets everything in motion:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf autom4te.cache
libtoolize --force --copy &&  aclocal &&  autoheader &&  automake --add-missing --force-missing --copy --foreign &&  autoconf
./configure && ./makeit
```

Comment: Your buildit script is too complex.  Do not call libtoolize, aclocal, etc explicitly.  Instead, just call autoreconf -i

Comment: Your usage of AC_INIT is extremetly antiquated.  In modern autoconf, AC_INIT should take 3 arguments: project name, version, point-of-contact.  What version of autoconf are you using?

Comment: AM_PROG_LIBTOOL should not be used anymore.  Use LT_INIT instead.

Answer (score 2):

For Bullet, there should be a bullet.pc file installed on your system which you can use with the autocong macro `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, the same way OGRE and OIS are included:

```
# in configure.ac 
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(BULLET, [bullet])

# in Makefile.am
OgreApp_CXXFLAGS= $(OGRE_CFLAGS) $(OIS_CFLAGS) $(BULLET_CFLAGS)
OgreApp_LDADD= $(OGRE_LIBS) $(OIS_LIBS) $(BULLET_LIBS)
```

---

If you add more unconditional dependencies, you might want to simplify both files by grouping them like this:

```
# in configure.ac 
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(DEPENDENCIES, [OGRE >= 1.2 OIS >= 1.0 bullet])

# in Makefile.am
OgreApp_CXXFLAGS= $(DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS)
OgreApp_LDADD= $(DEPENDENCIES_LIBS)
```

And as Jack Kelly wrote in the comments, if you have pkg-config >= 0.24 (released in 2010), you don't need to use `AC_SUBST` after `PKG_CHECK_MODULE`.

Comment: Don't `AC_SUBST` the variables set by `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, it is done for you already.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Makefile.am`:

```
OgreApp_LIBADD= -llib1 -llib2
```

Does that help?

Edit: or try appending `-llib1 -llib2` to the `OgreApp_LDADD=...` line, I'm not sure myself.

Comment: Trying OgreApp_LDADD causes an error. Adding the files to LDADD like this: OgreApp_LDADD= $(OGRE_LIBS) $(OIS_LIBS) /usr/local/lib/libBulletCollision.so /usr/local/lib/libBulletDynamics.so /usr/local/lib/libBulletMultiThreaded.so results in the inability to include a sample header file from bullet